# Why google appengine datastore entity key's value is so complex?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

```
Entity Kind  Account
Entity Key   ahJkZXZ-YnVmZmFsb2hvcm5ocmRyDQsSB0FjY291bnQYAgw
ID   2
```

why the entity key's value is so complex and how appengine generate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two dash-separated parts of the key are [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded strings, with the final padding characters removed. By decoding the two parts you get a couple of recognizable strings and a bunch of control characters:

```
$ base64 -d <<<ahJkZXZ=
j^Rdev
$ base64 -d <<<YnVmZmFsb2hvcm5ocmRyDQsSB0FjY291bnQYAgw=
buffalohornhrdr^M^K^R^GAccount^X^B^L
```

I suppose that GAE uses your own identifiers to generate this string, but since I am not familiar with it I am not aware of the exact algorithm.